# Which one is the long version of the Segal Bourbaki seminar article that Nora Ganter refers to on her TMF literature list?

Tags: reference-request, elliptic-cohomology

I mean the [extremely useful literature list](https://researchers.ms.unimelb.edu.au/%7Enganter@unimelb/talbot/index.html) compiled by Nora Ganter. One of the entries there is

> Segal: Bourbaki and the long version of the Bourbaki article

What I know is [the version on numdam](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=SB_1987-1988__30__187_0) (*Elliptic cohomology*, Astérisque, tome 161-162 (1988), Séminaire Bourbaki, exp. no 695, p. 187-201)

Is this the long version she has in mind or there exists a still longer one?

Of course I could just ask her but I thought some other people might occasionally become interested in the same question, so...

Comment: I asked Nora, and she says she can't recall! So hopefully someone else might know... Maybe Mike Hopkins? Or another of the Talbot workshop participants from that year?